# Codeigniter radio buttons callback validation error?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to display error message if no gender is selected using Codeigniter callback validation error...

### My HTML Page

```
<label class="control-label labeller" for="gender">Gender</label>
     <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Male">Male
     <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Female">Female
```

### My Controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'callback_gender');

public function gender($str)
{
    if ($str == '')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message( 'gender', 'Please Choose gender' );
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of times... Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$this->input->post('gender')` instead of `$str`

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
  }

  public function index() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'callback_gender');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

     // Load view

    } else {

     // Success Stuff
    }

  }


  public function gender() {
    if ($this->input->post('gender')) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message( 'gender', 'Please Choose gender' );
        return FALSE;
    }
  }

}
```

> Or on callback  `$this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender',
>   'callback_gender[gender]');`

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
  }

  public function index() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'callback_gender[gender]');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

     // Load view

    } else {

     // Success Stuff
    }

  }


  public function gender($str) {
    if ($str == '') {
        $this->form_validation->set_message( 'gender', 'Please Choose gender' );
        return FALSE;

    } else {
         return TRUE;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: @RobertWillis Do you have form tags

Comment: You don't have much detail in your question

Comment: Sir, its working... I followed your answer and its working... Thanks...